# Where to malloc user buffer? User code or library code?

Tags: c, malloc

I am writing a library which will be used by many applications.
Is there a preferred way to allocate a buffer?
Should the user malloc it in the main application? Or should the library function malloc it? Note that performance or space usage is not a concern. I am asking more from a good design perspective for developing API.

[1] Application allocates buffer space:

```
int main()
{
   char **abc = malloc (1024*sizeof(char*));
   abc[0] = malloc ..
   abc[1] = malloc ..

   foo(abc);
   free_all(abc);
}

/*================================*/

//external API
void foo(char **abc) {
    strncpy(abc[0], "hello\0", 6);
    strncpy(abc[1], "world\0", 6);
    //and so on
}
```

[2] Library function mallocs buffer

```
int main()
{
    char **abc = NULL;
    foo(&abc);
    free_all(abc);
}

/*================================*/

//external API
void foo(char ***abc)
{
    int num_elem = 32;
    *abc = malloc (num_elem * sizeof(char*));
    (*abc)[0] = malloc(6);
    (*abc)[1] = malloc(6); //and so on
    strncpy( (*abc)[0], "hello\0", 6);
    strncpy( (*abc)[1], "world\0", 6);
    //and so on
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

1. Will the user be able to determine how much memory is required?
2. Can memory requirement for one item change during its lifetime?

If the user can know how much space to allocate and the data does not change space requirements then it is acceptable for either the user or the library to manage the memory

If one of these points is not true, it would be best for the library to manage the space. To do otherwise would require additional communication between the user and the library to manage the memory. In the first case, to find out how much space is required and in the second to indicate that the library cannot perform a requested operation until the user allocates more space.

Answer (score 0):

Let user to choose: internal lib allocator or user-defined allocator.

Comment: I  have to develop the API and tell the user if he should pass a NULL pointer or an allocated buffer, so I have to make that decision.

Comment: Or make a function that will accept allocator as input parameter, for example. As you can see, there are various ways to achieve the thing.